# UITableViewCell. How do I just highlight cell during touch down?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom tableViewCell. I want to indicate user touch down by highlighting. The cell selection style is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`. In the parent controller I have set `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES`.

I should be good to go. Nope. Selection still sticks to the cell. What I want is selection indication only for the duration of the touch down. The appearance should immediately return to the unselected appearance on touch up.

How do I do this?

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: We have a winna! For the folks at home the actual method signature is deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:. Sweet. Cheers.

Comment: I can't believe that I spend so much to figure out this pain problem...
You just think cocoa touch will do that at didHighlightItemAtIndexPath
any way thanks @Dancreek

Answer (score 17):

Below Swift example uses `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` to change the background color of the cell on touch down and `didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath` to reset the color - see below:

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
  }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. The color doesn't reset on touch up

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:` and confirm that it's called on touch up? If you can confirm that, then the next culprit could be your color changing logic.

Comment: sorry I realized my issue was that I had 'delays content touches' selected in my storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

overwrite `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animate:(BOOL)animated` without calling super

Comment: The cell is selected only after touch up - the question wants to change the color on touch down.

Comment: Override - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animate:(BOOL)animated without calling super

Answer (score 1):

Update Zorayz answer.
Swift 5

Set when setup tableView(ViewDidLoad)

```
tableView.allowsSelection = true
```

Add this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SettingCell {
        cell.backView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SettingCell {
        cell.backView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

Custom cell with xib

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var backView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var describeLabel: UILabel!
    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addSettings()
    }
    
    private func addSettings() {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: "#101010")
        self.describeLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: "#676767")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    
    func setupCell(data: SettingModel) -> SettingCell {

        self.imageIcon.image = UIImage(named: data.iconImage)
        self.titleLabel.text = data.titleLabel
        self.describeLabel.text = data.describeLabel
        
        return self
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

It gets the backgroundview with cell border looking like seperator.Do not change the default tableview settings in Interface builder.Make sure UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone is NOT set to selectionstyle.  I am pasting the working code. :

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"PlayListCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
}
MPMediaPlaylist *playList = [playlistCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = playList.name;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
 // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Songs",[playList.items count]];
MPMediaItemCollection *playListMediaCollection = [playlistCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[self getImageForCollection:playListMediaCollection.items]];

// the main code which make it highlight

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170.0f/255.0 green:170.0f/255.0 blue:170.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
[bgColorView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[bgColorView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];


return cell;
```

}

Answer (score -4):

**I had the same issue.The code below perfectly worked for me.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to reload table on every touch event? It's absolutely wrong way how to do subject.

Comment: This turns the cell blue, but it stays that way and it only works on touchUpInside. What about touch down only?

Comment: The cell is marked selected only after touch up - the question wants to change the color on touch down; plus, I agree with @surfrider, why would you reload data?