# UITableView - Only highlight individual cell on touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I have an `UITableView` that has multiple rows. The user is only allowed to select 1 row. I want to show the grey selection effect only while touching the row, not after the row is selected.

I set the selection effect to Grey in interface builder. This allows me to see the selection effect while touching, but it also shows the grey selection color **after** I made my selection. To fix this I tried the following code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402278/6414904:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AnswerTableViewCell
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

This works partly. When I select a cell it only shows the Grey selection effect while touching the cell but after selecting a cell the grey selection effect is gone. This is what I want but with this code added it also allows the user to select **multiple** rows which I do not want. With this approach I also can't use the `didDeselectRowAt` method for other functionalities.

How do I create a selection effect which only shows during touch/hold but is removed after a selection while only allowing 1 row to be selected at all times?

Comment: `UITableView` has a property `allowsMultipleSelection`, it's probably set to `true` in your case. Set it to `false` in code or set `Selection` to be `Single Selection` for the table in the interface builder.

Comment: @ovejka this property is already set to Single Selection in IB. The weird part is that with the above code it does allow multiple selections. Removing the `deselectRow` method brings it back to single selection.

Comment: remove `let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AnswerTableViewCell` and see if it makes difference. You don't seem to be using it anyway.

Comment: this doesn't affect the desired goal @deville

Answer (score 1):

For this specially one delegate method is available.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 // do something here
}
```

Comment: This allows me to highlight the selected cell, however if the cell is quickly touched the effect of it being clicked doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Add `cell.setHighlighted(false, animated:true)` to your `didSelectRow` call.

If I'm not mistaken, didSelectRow is only called after you release the button.

Comment: Oddly enough it still causes the cell to remain highlighted after selection.

Comment: @Hapeki that is odd. My only other suggestion would be adding a didTouchUpInside event handler.